# have a clear, quick, decided look about

Tags: meaning, sentence

I don't understand this sentence：

> He(the mockingbird) was a clear gray, with white bars across his wings that flashed when he flew; ***every part of him* had a clear, quick, *decided* look *about it*.** (from [THE BAT-POET](http://www.apelslice.com/books/0-00-BRITE/1-880323-06-0/series5sem1.htm))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The parts are not looking about; rather, they each have a clear, quick and decided *appearance*.

Answer (score -1):

Every part of him created the impression of being clear, quick and decided.